# Log request payload in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

How can we log request payload/parameters before and after processing in filter of spring boot application.

For example:

```
/api/users/auth Body: `name:Vijay, place:bangalore...`
```

I have to log request body in filter before and after processing the request.

Comment: you can use java logging utility or other frameworks such as log4j or logback

Answer (score 7):

Spring Boot provides the `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` for this purpose.

You configure it like so:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter;


@Configuration
public class RequestLoggingFilterConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        filter.setIncludePayload(true);
        // truncate payloads
        filter.setMaxPayloadLength(1000);
        filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
        filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("Request received: ");
        return filter;
    }
}
```

And add a logger definition to your `logback.xml` like so:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="REQUEST_RESPONSE_FILE_APPENDER"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Spring Boot 2 Webflux with Netty: Error:(13, 15) java: cannot access javax.servlet.Filter
  class file for javax.servlet.Filter not found

Comment: `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` also puts the request payload in the "after request" log line. Kinda confusing matters if I want to log the response body/payload too.